# Copy cell range from one sheet to another in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy the data in "Sheet9" which starts in in Row 1 and Column H and I want to copy the data to different sheet "Quote Sheet Template"

When I run the script it I am not getting errors but it isn't copying the data.  Can anyone help?

`````
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet9');
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Quote Sheet Template');

  // get source range
  var source = copySheet.getRange(1,7,25,25);
  // get destination range
  var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(1,7,25,25);

  // copy values to destination range
  source.copyTo(destination);
}````
`````

Comment: Check your executions

Comment: Don't see anything wrong except for no function declaration.

Comment: Column H is column 8

Comment: I tried to replicate the issue. Your code should be able to copy the source range to your destination range. Besides the fact that it will start copying from column  G as pointed out by cooper column H is in index 8